# send multiple images over socket from java server to android client,trouble that you'll see just last image

Tags: java, android, sockets

My big problem that I send multiple images from java server to android clent over socket and all the images sending fine, but the problem with receive them, I see just the last one .

The java server :

```
//during the connecting
private void whileConnecting() throws IOException, AWTException, InterruptedException {  
    int i=0;
    while(i<5){
    System.out.println("i = " + i);
    capture = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(capture, "png", baos);
    baos.flush();
    System.out.println("Size of baos = " + baos.size());
    byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    baos = null;
    output.writeObject(buffer);
    output.flush();
    i++;
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Client android side :

```
try {
       connection = new Socket(getIntent().getStringExtra("ip"), 8080);
       input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
       int i = 0;
       while (i < 5) {
           i++;
           buffer = (byte[]) input.readObject();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "buffer length = " + buffer.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               //screenCapture.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.length));
           }
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }finally {
         try {
             connection.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error with closing connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     }
```

Comment: The Sulotion of this problem that to put all this code in AsyncTask :)